# Jars in Maven Central needs to go into Nexus OSS?

Tags: maven, nexus

I need to set up my own maven repository, since some open sourced libraries are not in Maven Central. I want to use Nexus OSS, and then I can upload the libraries I need to Nexus OSS.

My question is, do I also need to upload those libraries that are originally in Maven Central and I can directly use in POM to Nexus OSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nexus` is a proxy for global repositories. You can define in `Nexus` configuration what repositories are you going to use. You do not need to upload libraries that are accessible from configured global repositories.
You can also host your own repository for your local libraries. Everything is configurable.

When you configure your `Nexus` you need to just connect to it trough maven config and all **actions** are done behind the scene. Don't worry about it.

All libraries that are needed to compile your project, firstly are downloaded to your `Nexus` and then from `Nexus` to your local repo.

For example this is the easiest way to configure `Nexus` with your maven:
[Nexus - maven - Configuration](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/20943003-Configure-Maven-to-Download-from-Nexus)

Answer (score 1):

Not at all: In your local `$userprofile/.m2/settings.xml` file (as well as in every pom.xml, altough is not a good practice) you can define as many repositories as you want. And so, you will be able to reference artifacts published to different repositories.

Comment: In your pom file is bad practice and for a real setup you should define only one repository in your settings by using a repository manager like Nexus.

Comment: Yes, I agree with not to define repositories in POMs. I've updated my answer.